# C++ compiler does not like "using INLINE = extern inline"

Tags: c++, c++11, inline

There is a lot of information out there on the use of `inline` and how to properly do so for the desired intent such as here (which I am currently using as a reference) [Inline Functions in C](https://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/inline.html).

When I attempt to implement what is speficied in the page I get compiler errors for

```
using INLINE = extern inline;
```

and even just

```
using INLINE = extern;
```

The compiler says "expected type specifier before extern"

What I'm wondering is why can I use `using` this way?

Is it because `using` is really just reserved for types and substitutions?

### Post Answer

Thank you so much!  I totally missed the fact that I was reading through C reference.  This is good news as it didn't seem like there was a really good way to deal with things from what I was reading but it is probably that way as it is out of date compared to what they are doing in C++11 now.

Comment: Yes, using is for types. inline and extern are not types. You need to use #define.

Comment: You are asking C++ question but linking the reference page with C rules. Also [using](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) is for creating `type` alias, `inline` and `extern` are just `keywords`

Comment: The way you use `inline` in C is quite different from the way you use it in C++.  You can't get advice on using `using` from an article on C because `using` is not a part of C.  You're seeking guidance from a wholly inappropriate source — it is not surprising that you are confused when applying it to a mismatched target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it because using is really just reserved for types and substitutions?

I don't know what you mean by substitutions, but yes to the reservation for types. An alias declaration is for declaring new names for **types**. A pair of specifiers doesn't form a type. You can't even make it work by superficially adding a type name there, since the `extern` and `inline` specifiers only apply to object and function identifiers, and not their associated type.

The article uses a macro (`#define`) because token substitution is the only way to create user defined specifiers like you want to do.

It's also worth noting that in C++ `inline` and `extern inline` are the same thing. It's only in C (a different language to C++, and the subject of the linked article) that `inline` doesn't imply linkage, requiring you to specify `extern`.